# Using Google drive to store apps data in structured format- similar to dropbox datastore API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I am working on an app and want to store user's data in user's google-Drive.

After looking at [dropbox datastore api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore) I would like to use something similar to store structured data as dropbox does.

Is it possible to do with Google drive or its better to use Dropbox api in this case.

Comment: I'd be curious to hear why you ask the question rather than going with Dropbox if you like the Datastore API.  Cheryl's answer below covers the Google alternatives which I know of.

Full Disclosure: I'm a Dropbox engineer who worked on the Datastore API, so I'm explicitly interested in feedback on what causes developers to decide for/against using it.

Comment: @atwyman, main reason for us to prefer drive over dropbox is to be able to cover the user base who do not have dropbox accounts but are on gmail.

Comment: Also, while I do like Dropbox Datastore's API and it does perform well, its kind of useless without some efficient way to export data while Drive, the data is already in "spreadsheat" format and comes with user friendly export to tsv, csv, and other formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Drive Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/) to store structured data that is automatically kept up to date.

Or, depending on your use can, the [app data](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata) folder can be used to store configuration information that shouldn't be accessible to the user.